# Select MAX timestamp with JPA2 Criteria API

Tags: java, generics, jpa-2.0, java-ee-6, criteria-api

So my entity has:

```
@Column(name="TS", nullable=false)
private java.sql.Timestamp timestamp;
```

My generated MetaModel has:

```
public static volatile SingularAttribute<MyEntity,Timestamp> timestamp;
```

I want to select by the Max Timestamp value:

```
Root<MyEntity> root = query.from(MyEntity.class);
Expression maxExpression = cb.max(root.get(MyEntity_.timestamp));
```

But I am not allowed because:

> `max(Expression<N> x)`
>             Create an aggregate expression applying the numerical max operation.
>   `<N extends java.lang.Number>` Expression

Of course `Timestamp` does not extend `Number`.

How can I do a `MAX` on a `Timestamp` column using the typesafe Criteria API ?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Instead of [max](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#max(javax.persistence.criteria.Expression)) one should use [CriteriaBuilder.greatest](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#greatest%28javax.persistence.criteria.Expression%29) for Timestamp (and for Date, String and other Comparables as well). And if you ever need MIN for Timestamp, then use least method instead

Similar kind of issue can be be faced with less/greater/equal comparisons. Firs one accepts argument that extends Number, second one is for other comparables:

- [lt](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#lt(javax.persistence.criteria.Expression,%20javax.persistence.criteria.Expression)) vs. [lessThan](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#lessThan(javax.persistence.criteria.Expression,%20javax.persistence.criteria.Expression))
- [le](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#le(javax.persistence.criteria.Expression,%20javax.persistence.criteria.Expression)) vs. [lessThanOrEqualTo](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#lessThanOrEqualTo(javax.persistence.criteria.Expression,%20javax.persistence.criteria.Expression))
- [ge](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#ge(javax.persistence.criteria.Expression,%20javax.persistence.criteria.Expression)) vs. [greaterThanOrEqualTo](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#greaterThanOrEqualTo(javax.persistence.criteria.Expression,%20javax.persistence.criteria.Expression))
- [gt](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#gt(javax.persistence.criteria.Expression,%20javax.persistence.criteria.Expression)) vs. [greaterThan](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#greaterThan(javax.persistence.criteria.Expression,%20javax.persistence.criteria.Expression))

Comment: sub.where(cb.greatest(histories.get("activeDate"))); 
[ERROR]   required: javax.persistence.criteria.Expression<X>
[ERROR]   found: javax.persistence.criteria.Path<java.lang.Object>
[ERROR]   reason: inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)

Comment: @SeSong same problem, what do I do?

Comment: I use max instead 
sub.where(cb.max(histories.get(History_.activeDate.getName())));

Comment: And CriteriaBuilder least() for MIN.

Comment: Yes, that's what is told in second sentence.