# Spring Data JPA @Query - select max

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I m trying to write a query using `select max`&`where` with `@Query`

**The following won't work, how can I fix it?**

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
interface IntermediateInvoiceRepository extends JpaRepository<Invoice, String> {

@Query("SELECT max(i.sequence) " +
        "FROM Invoice as i " +
        "WHERE i.fleetId = :fleetId" +
        "   AND i.sequence IS NOT NULL")
Long findMaxSequence(@Param("fleetId") String fleetId);

}
```

I've run into another answer but it is using the entity manager explicitly, os its not the same

[How do I write a MAX query with a where clause in JPA 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348354/how-do-i-write-a-max-query-with-a-where-clause-in-jpa-2-0)

**the error is :**

```
2018-09-14T09:27:57,180Z  [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication     - Application startup failed
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findMaxSequence found for type Invoice!
```

the invoice class (simplified for brevity):

```
@Entity
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@Table(name = "invoices", indexes = {
        @Index(name = "IDX_FLEET", columnList = "fleetId", unique = false)
        ,
        @Index(name = "IDX_USERSSS", columnList = "userId", unique = false)
        ,
        @Index(name = "IDX_TIME", columnList = "invoiceDate", unique = false)
        ,
        @Index(name = "IDX_SEQUENCE", columnList = "sequence", unique = false)
})
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Invoice implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "CHAR(36)")
    @Id
    private String id;

    @Column
    private long sequence;
```

...

**Update:**

- maybe a work-around with findOne with DESC sort on the sequence
  column?

  @Query("SELECT i.sequence " +
              "FROM Invoice as i " +
              "WHERE i.fleetId = :fleetId " +
              "ORDER BY i.sequence DESC ")
      Long getMaxSequence(@Param("fleetId") String fleetId);

But i need to LIMIT the resultset to 1 somehow

**Update 2:**

fixed the `import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;` still in error

Comment: Spring Data is very conventional, the method name starting with find might be throwing it off. What happens when you rename the method to 'getMaxSequence' ?

Comment: the same: 
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property getMaxSequence found for type Invoice!

Comment: can you try using nativequery and check if that gives the same problem

Comment: Could you check if you're using _org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query_ annotations instead of any other?

Comment: i m using : 
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Query;

Comment: So that seems pretty wrong then

Comment: i ve changed the Query import to the jpa one. i get a 
java.lang.NullPointerException now . i ve added  AND i.sequence IS NOT NULL in my query (pls see the update). still the same error.

Comment: i ve found a workaround using Pageable.

Comment: `@Query("select max(i.sequence) ...")` is ok, maybe you get some other error but not about this. [This unit test code(repository.getMaxCode)](https://github.com/start-java/start-spring-data-jpa/blob/18.10.0/src/test/java/tech/simter/start/springdatajpa/repository/entity1/GetMaxCodeMethodTest.java#L57) can proved it. Beside that the annotation `@Repository` is not neccessary and should be removed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're using JPA repositories, use:

```
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query
```

annotation instead of

```
org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Query
```

You can create a query method, without using @Query annotation, like:

Invoice findFirstByFleetIdOrderBySequenceDesc(String fleetId);

that return the invoice that you need.

Answer (score 0):

I ve found a workaround :

create a simple repository method returning `Page` and accepting a `Pageable`:

```
Page<Invoice> findByFleetId(String fleetId, Pageable pageable);
```

This way we can imitate an `ORDER BY sequence LIMIT 1` via the following:

```
long maxNewSeq = 0;
PageRequest pageRequest = new PageRequest(0, 1, Sort.Direction.DESC, "sequence");
Page<Invoice> pageableInvoices = invoiceRepository.findByFleetId(invoice.getFleetId(), pageRequest);
if(pageableInvoices.getTotalElements() > 0){
    maxNewSeq = pageableInvoices.getContent().get(0).getSequence();
}

invoice.setSequence(Math.max(0, maxNewSeq) + 1);
```

seems to work like a charm.